# How to get name for a record and display it on form

Tags: python, odoo

I got a problem, after saving a record , for view displays model name plus record number . like in the screen shot . i want only record name appear there . thanks in advance

[image: my form with model name and , record number]

please help , except _rec_name , cause here i get multiples ids from multiple tables

Comment: Does your object has a field called 'name' ? If not, try to add a 'name' field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenERP/Odoo will call name_get on your model to display this.  If you override name_get you can return whatever you want, otherwise it will use the name_get on the BaseModel class.

This will:

1. Return the field specied by you as _rec_name on your model
2. Look for a column called "name" and use that.
3. Auto-generate one.

The easiest thing to do as Quentin said is have a column called "name" but sometimes it doesn't make sense.  For example, in product.supplierinfo the name field is actually the supplier ID - seems like someone was too lazy to do it properly.

Failing that, define a _rec_name field or override name_get yourself but there are a couple of got-chas.

1. Unlike functional fields, name_get returns a list of tuples where each tuple is (id, name).
2. If you use a column other than name or you override name_get, you also need to think about overriding name_search to give the user a consistent behaviour.  The product.product model has good examples of this.